# Finding last row before coordinate change in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, geopandas

I have a csv file with objects categorized by IDs, with their latitude and longitude, and timestamp. 
There are multiple rows of latitudes and longitudes that often repeat themselves, but there are sudden changes in either latitude or longitude and I need to find the specific point where that movement started. I would want to capture even minimal Lat/longs changes, i.e. -20.0, 90 followed by -20.0001, 90.002.

Basically, I want to find the **last row prior to any change** in either the latitude or the longitude for each object. 
There can be multiple rows with the new lat/longs, so `remove_duplicates()` in pandas is not a viable option. 
The output would need to be in csv format.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this will work for your implementation (in the future, please add some sort of minimal reproducible example, see Zeytinci's comment), but I would use the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) function on the dataframe.

I'm not sure if you data are rows or columns, but this function will find the difference between the current row/column and the previous row/column (it has other uses too, check the docs). You can use it to generate a (separate) dataframe which contains these differences, and then you just the [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) command (or convert to a `numpy` array and use [nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to find the places where your lon/lat values changed.

For instance, if your data look like

```
ID,longitude,latitude
----------
1,100,100
2,100,100
3,100,100
4,100.01,100
5,100.01,100.01
6,100.01,100.01
```

I'm assuming you'd just set the ID row as the index, or just ignore it for now. Running this through the `diff` function would give:

```
ID,longitude,latitude
----------
1,NaN,NaN
2,0,0
3,0,0
4,0.01,0
5,0,0.01
6,0,0
```

Converting to a `numpy` array and using `nonzero` will give you

```
arr = np.array([[np.NaN,0,0,0.01,0,0],[np.NaN,0,0,0,0.01,0]])
np.nonzero(arr)

>>> (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 3, 0, 4]))
```

where the result gives you the indices in the array which are nonzero (the indices where the latitude/longitude changed). Just subtract one from the row to find the rows before each change.

Comment: does this work if the lat/longs are something other than 0 to begin with?

Comment: @map.apps sorry for the late reply, yes, the diff function just takes the difference between adjacent rows or columns, so it doesn't matter what the first lat/long values are, it'll only pick out where they change